# Payeezy credit card payment integration using HMAC

Tags: apex, callout, crypto

I was recently working on **Payeezy** ([link](https://developer.payeezy.com/payeezy-api/apis/post/transactions-3))  integration with **sales force**. Payeezy was using **HMAC** to generate authorization header with help of certain **apiKey**, **Token**, **TimStamp**, **Nonce** and **API Secret** key. if you follow the link you will have sample request available in there online developer doc.

Challenged i was facing in **apex class** while generating using "**Crypto.generateMac**" which never matched compared to developer site even after using same data.

But using "crypto-js.js" library in apex page i am able to generate the same authorization header.

Here is the sample code

```
<apex:page applyHtmlTag="false" sidebar="false" applyBodyTag="false" cache="false" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false"
       controller="payeezeController" >

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/hmac-sha256.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/enc-hex.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <script>
        var apiKey = 'o************************89P';
        var nonce = '3*****************0';
        var timestamp = '1575278390754';
        var token = 'f*******************************t';
        var data = apiKey + nonce + timestamp + token + '{"transaction_type":"authorize","method":"credit_card","amount":"1299","currency_code":"USD","credit_card":{"type":"visa","cardholder_name":"John Smith","card_number":"4788250000028291","exp_date":"1020","cvv":"123"}}';
        var privateKey = '5*******************************************';

        var signatureBlob = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(data, privateKey);
        var sign = btoa(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(signatureBlob));

        console.log('sign : ' + sign);                          
    </script>

</body>
```

My requirement was we need to capture amount first & generate transaction id store in the sales-force and we need to deduct once whole application has submitted successfully.

Deduction of the amount i need to be done from apex class only. I didn't find any article or answer online which will help me generate equivalent HMAC which used to generate from above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially HMAC was generate by apex using **"crypto.generateMac"** which very small and 32 bit in size, found a article we need to convert HMAC blob to base64 using **"EncodingUtil.base64Encode"** which will give you 64 character size which is again small compare to what i need to is around 88 character in size in order get work.

Again i reach end of solution, later i used Java-script **"crypto-js.js"** library to reverse Engineer to get the same solution in apex class and it **worked for me**. So i thought of writing article it may help other's too, if they came across same Payeezy integration in Apex class/Apex Page.

```
    String apiKey = 'o************************89P';
    String nonce = '3*****************0'';
    String timestamp = '1575354902763';
    String token = 'f*******************************t';
    String data = apiKey + nonce + timestamp + token + '{"merchant_ref":"Astonishing-Sale","transaction_type":"authorize","method":"credit_card","amount":"1299","currency_code":"USD","credit_card":{"type":"visa","cardholder_name":"John Smith","card_number":"4788250000028291","exp_date":"1020","cvv":"123"}}';
    String privateKey = '5*******************************************'';
    Blob privateKeyBlob = Blob.valueOf(privateKey);
    Blob urlBlob = Blob.valueOf(data);
    Blob signatureBlob = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256', urlBlob, privateKeyBlob);
    string str=EncodingUtil.convertToHex(signatureBlob);
    blob b=Blob.valueOf(str);
    String encoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(b);
    system.debug('signature is : ' +encoded);
```